# How to detect my app from foreground to recent apps screen in Android

Tags: android

In iOS, go to recent apps screen will trigger pause with lifecycle, but Android will not trigger pause.

How do I detect the same use case?

Comment: It actually triggers onPause() of the Activity....this is the normal workflow for Activities Lyfecycle.

Comment: `onPause` method of the Activity will be called

Comment: This is the result of my recording: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bJ8HlqLlMid8-pvK_8YmqPDt7TcRe9YE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

onPause() will not be called in this behavior. I finally found out that onWindowFocusChanged is called when App goes to recent screen.

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

    if (hasFocus) {
        // Get back to Application
    } else {
        // Goes to recent screen
    }
}
```